# Lema prior to completion of finite normed vectorial spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $(V, \mathbb{K},||.||)$, with $n=$dim($V)< \infty$ and $\beta= \lbrace u_1, u_2, ... u_n \rbrace$ a basis of $V$. I want to prove that $\forall x \in V$, if $x=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i u_i$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists c>0$ $\backepsilon$  $c \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_i | \leq ||x||= ||\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i u_i||$...(1). I found this result is being used on a proof about completion of finite dimentional normed spaces.

My attempt so far: By induction on $n$.
The case for $n=1$ is trivial since $|a_1| || u_1 ||= ||a_1 u_1 || =||x||$ and $u_1 \neq 0_V$

Then I tried to use the property $| |x| - |y| |\leq |x-y|$ so I obtained something like this:

$\exists c_1 >0 \backepsilon$  $$c_1 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_i| - |a_{n+1}| ||u_{n+1} ||$$

$$\leq  || \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i u_i|| - |a_{n+1}| ||u_{n+1} ||$$

$$\leq |\text{   } ||\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i u_i|| - |a_{n+1}| ||u_{n+1} || \text{   } | $$

$$\leq ||\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i u_i +a_{n+1} u_{n+1} || $$

$$= ||\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i u_i || =x$$

But I can't go further. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: The way you wrote it in the statement, it seems that $c$ depends on $x$ (which, I assume, is not the case).

Comment: It's not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $s=\sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_i|$. If $s=0 \Rightarrow a_j=0$ $1\leq j \leq n$. Therefore (1) is true $\forall c \in \mathbb{K}$, in partiular $\forall c >0$.

Supose now that $s>0 \Rightarrow$

$||\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_j x_j || \geq c ( \sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_j|) =cs =c|s| \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{|s|} ||\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_j x_j ||\geq c \Leftrightarrow ||\dfrac{1}{s} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_j x_j ||\geq c $

$\Leftrightarrow ||  \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\dfrac{a_j}{s}) x_j || \geq c \Leftrightarrow || \sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_j x_j || \geq c$.

Where $\beta_j = \dfrac{a_j}{s}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\beta_j| =1$.

Thus, (1) is equivalent to prove that for a l.i. subset $\{x_1, x_2 , ... x_n \} \subset V$, $\exists c \in \mathbb{K} \backepsilon \forall \beta_1, \beta_2 , ... \beta_n  \in \mathbb{K} \backepsilon \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\beta_j| =1 \Rightarrow ||\sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_j x_j || \geq c $ ... (2)

By contradiction, suppose that its false. (i.e. for a l.i. subset $\{x_1, x_2 , ... x_n \} \subset V$ $(\forall c \in \mathbb{K})$ ($\exists \beta_j \in \mathbb{K}, 1\leq j \leq n$) [($\sum_{j=1}^{n}|\beta_j|=1$) $\Rightarrow$ ($||\sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_j x_j ||\leq c$)].

With this, we have in particular that $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}$   $\exists \{\beta_{1}^{(m)},\beta_{2}^{(m)},...,\beta_{n}^{(m)} \} \subset \mathbb{K}$ $\backepsilon $ $\sum_{j=1}^{n}|\beta_{j}^{(m)}|=1 \Rightarrow ||\sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_j^{(m)} x_j ||\leq \dfrac{1}{m}$

$\Rightarrow \exists \{ y_m \} \subset V$, where $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}, y_m = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_{j}^{(m)} x_j \backepsilon \text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty} ||y_m||=0$ because $ ||y_m || \leq 1/m  $.

Because $\sum_{i=1}^{n} | \beta_j^{(m)} | =1 \forall m \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow \forall j \in \{1,2,...n\}$,   $0 \leq |\beta_j^{m}| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} | \beta_j^{(m)} | =1$ $\Rightarrow 0\leq |\beta_j^{(m)}| \leq 1  \forall m \in \mathbb{N} , 1 \leq j \leq n$. That implies that the sequence $\{ \beta_j^{(m)}\}=\{ \beta_j^{(1)} , \beta_j^{(2)} , ...\}$ is bounded and by construction countable $\Rightarrow $ (Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem) $\{ \beta_j^{(m)}\}´ \neq \emptyset$ ($1\leq j \leq n$). Let $\beta_j \in \{ \beta_j^{(m)}\}´$ ($1\leq j \leq n$)  $\Rightarrow \exists $ a subsequence $\{ \beta_j^{(k_m)}\} \subset \{ \beta_j^{(m)}\}-\{\beta_j \} \backepsilon $ $\text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty } \beta_{j}^{(k_m)} = \beta_j$ for ($1\leq j \leq n$).

Let $j=1$. taking the natural numbers that index the convergent subsequence $\{ \beta_1^{(k_m)}\}$, we generate  a corresponding subsequence of $ \{ y_m \} $, wich we denote by $\{ y_{1,m} \}$.

Let $j=2$, taking the natural numbers that index the convergent subsequence $\{ \beta_2^{(k_m)}\}$ and intersecting them with the subscripts of $\{ y_{1,m} \}$, we generate a corresponding subsequence of $\{ y_{1,m} \}$ wich we denote by $\{ y_{2,m} \}$.

Continuing with this way, afther $n$ steps, we obtain a subsequence $ \{ y_{n,m} \} = \{ y_{n,1}. y_{n,2} , .... \}$ of $ \{ y_m \} $ whose terms are of the form
\begin{align}
& y_{n,m} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \gamma_{j}^{(m)}x_{j} &   &  \text{with} & ( \sum_{j=1}^{n} |\gamma_{j}^{(m)}| =1 ) \\
\end{align}
whose scalars $ \gamma_{j}^{(m)}$ satisfy $\text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty} \gamma_{j}^{(m)} = \beta_j$ for ($1\leq j \leq n$). Therefore

\begin{equation}
\text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty} y_{n,m} = \text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \gamma_{j}^{(m)} x_j = \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j \text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty} \gamma_{j}^{(m)} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}  x_j \beta_j = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \beta_{j} x_j := y \end{equation}.

Where also
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^{n} |\beta_j | = \sum_{j=1}^{n} | \text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty} \gamma_{j}^{(m)} | = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty} | \gamma_{j}^{(m)} | = \text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty}  \sum_{j=1}^{n} | \gamma_{j}^{(m)} | = \text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty}  1 = 1
\end{equation}.

$\therefore \sum_{j=1}^{n} |\beta_j | = 1 \Rightarrow $ not all $ b_j $ are zero. Since $ \{ x_1, x_", ..., x_n\}$ is l.i. $\Rightarrow y \neq 0$, that can be easily seen by contradiction.

On the other side, $\text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty} y_n,m =y \Rightarrow \text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty} ||y_n,m || = ||y|| $ because the continuity of the norm. Remember for hypothesis that we had $\text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty} ||y_m || =0 $, and by the fact that $ \{ y_{n,m} \} $ is a subsequence of a convergent sequence, it must be that $\text{lim}_{m \rightarrow \infty} ||y_n,m ||=0$ $\Rightarrow $ (uniqueness) $||y||=0 \Leftrightarrow y=0$

$\therefore y=0 \wedge y \neq 0 \mathbb{!}$ So (2) must be true and with that it's also true (1). **Q.E.D**

This proof can be found on page 72 of the book written by Erwin Kreyszig "Introductory functional analysis with applications" (Wiley, 1978).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the proof cannot work down the path you chose.

What you are trying to prove is the nontrivial part of the argument that all norms are equivalent on a finite-dimensional normed space.

The usual way is to consider the map $\Gamma:\mathbb K^n\to V$ given by
$$
\Gamma(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_ju_j.
$$
This map is trivially bijective, and the reverse inequality of the one you want holds, so $\Gamma$ is bounded. The set $$B=\{(a_j):\ \sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|=1\}\subset\mathbb K^n$$ is compact, so the continuous function $$(a_j)\longmapsto\Big\|\sum_{j=1}^na_ju_j\Big\|$$ maps $B$ to a compact subset of $\mathbb K$. In particular there exists $d$ such that $\|\Gamma((a_j))\|≤d$ on $B$. This gives
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|=1\}\leq d\,\Big\|\sum_{j=1}^na_ju_j\Big\|.$$